# How exactly (step-by-step) do you define the entries in a python dictionary using a for loop?

Tags: python, file, text

Here is my code so far:

```
def a(nameOfFile):

    f = open(nameOfFile)
    text = f.read()
    lines = text.split() # splits each word into string

    d = {}

    for x in range(len(lines)-1): # for each word in new line
        lines[x] = lines[x+1]

    return d
```

I am trying to go from a text file to a dictionary that lists each word and the possible words that can followed it. For instance, if the text file contains the sentence, "John is tall. Sunny thinks he will win," then the output should be {'John': [is], 'is': [tall] … } and so on.

I can't seem to grasp how to define the dictionary. I saw some examples that use a key, value code but we haven't learned that so I don't think I am need that. The examples in our class material use for loops so I am trying to use that.

Thanks, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to create dictionary entries in `d` for all consecutive `lines[x]`, `lines[x+1]` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

```
>>> st="John is tall. Sunny thinks he will win, and win he will if she thinks so."
>>> wl=[e.rstrip('.,') for e in st.split()]
>>> words={}
>>> for w1, w2 in zip(wl[::2], wl[1::2]):
...    words.setdefault(w1, []).append(w2)
... 
>>> words
{'and': ['win'], 'will': ['win'], 'if': ['she'], 'tall': ['Sunny'], 
 'John': ['is'], 'thinks': ['he', 'so'], 'he': ['will']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop doesn't use `d` at all.

`split()` creates a list of the words in your string. It's default is to split on any kind of whitespae.

```
d = {}

s = "Put us in the dictionary"

words = text.split() # ['Put', 'us', 'in', 'the', 'dictionary']

start = 0
for word in words:
    index = words.index(word, start) + 1
    start = index
    try:
        d[word] = words[index]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

**Output:**

```
>>> print d 
{'Put': 'us', 'the': 'dictionary', 'us': 'in', 'in': 'the'}
```

Note that dicts don't have an obvious ordering

Comment: `split()` with no argument isn't the same as `split(" ")`. It spits on any amount of any kind of whitespace. If you used both to split `"foo    bar"`, you get different results: `"foo   bar".split() == ["foo", "bar"]` versus `"foo   bar".split(" ") == ["foo", "", "", "bar"]`. Also, `words.index(word)` will only find the first occurance of `word`, so for words that appear repeatedly you'll just get the word that follows the first one repeated.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks, you're absolutely right. I believe I have rectified my post.